# ArcMap not respecting advanced sort in related tables?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, relates

ArcMap 10.2.2 doesn’t respect the advanced sort in related tables, I couldn’t figure out why the ArcMap doesn’t respect the advanced sorted values when the sorted table is related to other feature calss? 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: While graphics are nice, I really need words which describe your expectations before I can understand the question.

Comment: I believe he's set up advanced sorting on the UrbanMasterPlans table, which is connected to community points by relate. But when you identify a community point and it pulls up the related table entries, those entries are not respecting the sort set up for the table. I wouldn't expect this, since as I understand it the sort is a property of the view of that table (just like layers are views of data) and doesn't actually affect the data itself. He wants the related records in Identify to sort by year.

Comment: Well many thanks Chris for your elaboration this is really what I want, and if you wouldnt expect to have this done by sorting the table, how can I overcome this problem ?

Comment: Physically sort it

Comment: Thanks felix, why do I need to physically sort the table? And also this table is very dynamic and always I need to add entries with different approval years

Comment: The table view has no relationship to any other window or tool in ArcMap and nothing transfers from it other than hiding of fields.  The identify window is not a table at all in any sense.  It is a tree-view object which is a completely different object from a table view.  The option in the Identify windows affects the entire window and specifically says it either is unsorted or Ascending sorted. While I would support a descending sort option in the Identify window, I would actively oppose any idea that tried to let the table view control the identify window.

Answer (score 1):

You could trick the display to show the years in the order you want by altering the Display tab expression field to do a formula that made an Ascending Sort behave like a Descending sort.  At least at version 10.2, multiplying a positive number to become a negative number reverses the sort of the numbers of the related table in the Identify window and is in ascending numerical order not ascending alphabetical order (so -10001 is above -10000, which is above -2000, which is above -1000).

Set the Identify window to apply an Ascending Sort to the entire window.  Then on the Display tab for your table make the expression:  -1 * [ApprovalYear]

if ApprovalYear is a string field make the expression:  -1 * CLng([ApprovalYear])

Explain that the "-" just means that you have removed the rest of the date and only retained the year portion and to otherwise ignore it.

Comment: Many thanks Richard for your input I tried to set the expression of the table as you mentioned but I still have the same issue here, I also tried to right click on the relate tree and then choose sort ascending but it fixed the display of the year, but doing this doesn’t physically change their correct sort because when I remove the tick form sort descending to see how really “naturally” the identify works the go back the a random sorting, you would ask me why I need them to be naturally sorted ?This is because that my web mapping application reads the values as they naturally sorted

Comment: Please have a look at this ![http://i.stack.imgur.com/OvDYU.jpg][1]

Comment: The identify tool is the wrong tool to do anything like you are describing and the Desktop Identify tool doesn't exist in a web mapping application as far as I know.  If you are deal with a web app, stop using at the Identify tool entirely.

Comment: many thanks Richard, what I am trying to do is to sort the entries of the related table according to the approval year, so the end user of my web mapping application can view them in the correct sort, the only way to do this is to sort the valuse at the level of ArcGIS ( desktop and server ), I hope to find a method do do this, since my web mapping application ( Geocortex essentials ) sorts the values as it is in ArcGIS

Comment: Nothing in a table view or the identify window will work.  They operate only in Desktop in memory for all sorting, so it is not permanent or transferable outside of Desktop.  Only the geoprocessing tool Sort will actually physically reorder the records to follow a descending order as far as I know.  It will get out of whack the moment a new record is added to the related table that has a more current related date for a feature and the tool would have to be run again.